# using HQL to concatenate strings from multiple rows

Tags: nhibernate

Consider a table holding names, with three rows:

Peter
Paul
Mary

using NHibernate HQL I want to  retrieve all the names as a single string  "Peter, Paul, Mary" to put it inside a single DTO object field. is there a way to do this kind of concatenation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

It's not possible to do string column aggregation in SQL, except maybe by using specific RDBMS features.

Just bring all the names and concatenate them client-side,

Answer (score 0):

It is too simple to implement this in C#, so it's not worth to try too hard to tweak NHibernate to do it (you may use functions or formula or ...)

```
class MyDto
{
  string Name1 { get; set; }
  string Name2 { get; set; }
  string Name3 { get; set; }

  string Names
  { 
    get 
    {
      return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", Name1, Name2, Name3)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: he has the names in rows, not columns